# php export text file without meta data

Tags: php, html

I have a string which contains data from a SQL query, and I try to export it to text file. But I only want the columns `name` and `data`, I do not want the meta data. I used the following code:

```
header('Content-type: application/txt');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="day2.txt"');
echo "$header\n$data";
```

The output is like the following. How can I get only the content inside the `body`? I do not want the `html` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>"1340129" "2013-04-08" "true" "true"</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mate, just do `echo $data;`

Comment: what is in `$header`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you ask how can you get only the content inside the body form a html document to serve it as a text file.

You could use a following snippet for this

```
<?php

$d = new DOMDocument;
$m = new DOMDocument;

// In case if you have an html document in a variable or so
$d->loadHTML('<html><head></head><body>123</body></html>');

// You could use it in case html or so document is a file resource  
#$d->loadHtml(file_get_contents('/path/to/desired/file.html'));

$b = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($b->childNodes as $child) {
    $m->appendChild($m->importNode($child, true));
}

// $m->saveHTML(); will hold only 123 in this case
echo $m->saveHTML();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove all HTML and only get the content, use the following

instead of

> echo "$header\n$data";

use

> echo strip_tags($header."\n".$data);